# How to use database function in other activity

Tags: android, database, function, android-activity

I'm trying to delete the rows in my database. Here for I'm using a function that I Have declared DatabaseOpenHelper:

```
    public void deleteall(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String delete = "TRUNCATE FROM tweets";
    db.delete(SCORE_TABLE,null,null);
      }
```

Now i'm using the 'Menu' to start a new activity that must clear my table. 
I'm trying to summon the function but it doesn't work. This is the code is use:

```
    public class ResetDatabase {


     public void main(String[] args) {
       DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(this);
       db.deleteall();
     }

}
```

but it gives errors. They suggest that i change DatabaseConnector(Conetext) to DatabaseConnector(ResetDatabase) but then my other functions give errors. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

YOur database connector takes a Context in the constructor.  You're passing in a ResetDatabase object, which is not a Context.  So you're passing in the wrong thing.  Pass in a Context (such as your Activity object) instead.

Comment: hmm I dont quit understand your answer. What would be the Activity object you are talking about ?

Comment: If you don't know what an Activity is you need to read some Android tutorials-  its the main workflow that you're implementing.

Comment: I found the solution I was working i the wrong activity. This my solution I'm now working in the DatabaseConnector and used this code:

        public void resetTable(String table_name, String create_table_name, String extraSQL)
 {
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(table_name))
   database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+table_name);
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(create_table_name))
   database.execSQL(create_table_name);
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(extraSQL))
   database.execSQL(extraSQL);
 }